# Custom sidebar shows 1 after the sidebar content

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a new theme for a website.

I created a new sidebar widget for footer area using register_sidebar hook.

Now when I entered some content in the sidebar widget from `Appearance -> Widgets` I get "1" displaying after each column in the footer.

Kindly see the [screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxsiY.png)

Please someone help me get rid of that. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you might added ol - ordered list while registering the widget. so it is displaying 1 at front

Comment: Can you post your `register_sidebar()` function code here?

Comment: The following is my code,

Comment: register_sidebar(
    array(
            'id' => 'footer_widget1',
            'name' => __( 'Footer Area 1', 'cruzbytes' ),
            'before_widget' => '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 footer-widget">',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title' => '</h3>'
        )    
    );